# Proportion request sql

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table of accidents and output the share of accidents number 2 to all accidents I wrote this code, but I can not make it work:

```
select ((select count("ID") from "DTP" where "REASON"=2)/count("REASON"))
from "DTP"
group by "ID"
```

[image]

Comment: What is `ДТП`? Also, please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...? Finally: sample data and desired results would make your question clearer.

Comment: What does the source data look like? What does the expected results look like? What result are you getting that is not working?

Comment: Also, if you're getting an error, you might need to put ID in your select clause since you're grouping by ID.

Comment: i think there is enough info to understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (not tested):

```
select id, count(case reason when 2 then 1 end)/count(*) as proportion
from   your_table
--     where  ...  (if you need to filter, for example by date)
group  by id
;
```

`count(*)` counts all the rows in a group (that is, all the rows for each separate `id`). The `case` expression returns 1 when the `reason` is `2` and it returns `null` otherwise; `count` counts only non-null values, so it will count the rows where the `reason` is `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `avg()`:

```
select id,
       avg(case when reason = 2 then 1.0 else 0 end)
from "DTP"
group by "ID"
```

This produces the ratio for each `id` -- based on your sample query.  If you only want one row for all the data, then:

```
select avg(case when reason = 2 then 1.0 else 0 end)
from "DTP";
```